# LoopBack Angular SDK's upsert includes ID in PATCH, causing an error

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using the generated Angular SDK from a LoopBack 3 API I have set up, but am running into an issue with the `$save()` method on the generated `$resource`. This method is mapped to the `upsert` action, which itself is mapped to `patchOrCreate`. The issue is that the entire model object is sent to the PATCH API when calling `$save()`, including the `id` of the model. I'm using a MongoDB backend, and have `idInjection` set to true, which means `forceId` is also true. This throws the following error on `$save()`:

> Unhandled error for request PATCH /api/Foo?id=58995169468d951cbf546ce4: ValidationError: The `Foo` instance is not valid. Details: `id` can't be set (value: 58995169468d951cbf546ce4).

I can get around this error by setting `forceId` to false, but that opens up security issues. I can also work around it by modifying the generated services file and adding a real `upsert` action to the `$resource` that uses PUT instead of PATCH and modifies the URL to include the id. This still triggers a warning about the ID, but it works and doesn't throw any errors. Editing generated code is not something I want to do, however.

What's the correct solution to this? I'd like to use `$save()` yet still maintain security, while not editing generated files.

Answer (score 0):

Set "forceId": false in your model and it will look like this
{
  "name": "Product",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "forceId": false,
}

See more info at http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/3.0-Release-Notes.html#models-with-auto-generated-ids-reject-user-provided-id-values